# What to do with questions with answers that are too hard to understand?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, migration

We had a question on christianity.se

> https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/63957/why-does-romans-519-say-many-instead-of-all

Which is probably an OK question for Hermeneutics but we can't migrate it because it is already, technically, asked here:

[What sort of phrasing is "the many" in Romans 5?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/20614/what-sort-of-phrasing-is-the-many-in-romans-5)

Unfortunately the answers were, by admission in now-deleted comments, too dense for the OP on the Christianity site to parse.  What can be done for users like this?    I suspect it happens more often than people let on because rarely do people make honest comments like "I don't understand any of those answers".   And we probably turn away a lot of people who could benefit from our collective watered down knowledge.

Does anybody have any ideas what to do in cases like this?

Comment: How do you know the OP won't be able to understand the answers?

Comment: @curiousdannii shoot, her comments were removed.  In any event, the OP on the C.SE question asked another commentor to answer on C.SE with an answer she could understand.  I think the answers on this site are a little much.  But the question was long and met the criteria.  Seems like there should be some wiggle room for people to ask basic and expert questions on the same topic.